# C++ Creating an Array?

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop

So I have an array of vertices and I am trying to fill in the array with data from a file.

Right now my code looks like the following:

```
    int VertexCount = Input.get();
    MVertex Vertices[4] =
    {
        {0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,},
        {1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,},
        {0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,},
        {1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,},
    };
```

Right now it works just fine, except for using VertexCount to initialize the size of the array, but I want to get it so depending on the vertex count I need a for-loop to fill in the data for me. I wanna keep the same array format because for some reason it doesn't work any other way, but like this. I was thinking something along the lines of:

```
    int VertexCount = Input.get();
    MVertex Vertices[VertexCount] =
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < VertexCount; i++)
        {
            {Input.get(), Input.get(), Input.get(),},
        }
    };
```

But that doesn't work I just get some syntax errors. Can someone please show me how to write it?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the declaration for `MVertex`.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to do too many things all at one time. You need to break this up into two steps:

1. Declare the array and allocate the array:

   ```
   int VertexCount = Input.get();
   MVertex* Vertices = new MVertex[VertexCount];
   ```
2. Initialize the elements of the array:

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < VertexCount; i++)
   {
       MVertex v;
       v.x = Input.get();
       v.y = Input.get();
       v.z = Input.get();

       Vertices[i] = v;
   }
   ```

Note that I create the `MVertex` object separately. In my opinion, this makes the intent of your code more clear. It also helps you write the code because you concentrate on one thing at a time instead of trying to do several steps all at once with more complex syntax.

I also assume the three fields in `MVertex` are named `x`, `y`, and `z`; change these as appropriate.

Since this code allocates a dynamic array, you **must** free the allocated memory when you are finished using it with the statement

```
delete[] Vertices;
```

Answer (score -1):

To create an array of variable size, use the new operator

```
MVertex* Vertices = new MVertex Vertices[VertexCount];
```

to create the array on the heap (and remember to delete[] it later), or use an STL container like std::vector.

Comment: This is only a partial answer since it does not illustrate how to initialize the elements of the allocated array.